# Make a model field choose from a database of users

Tags: django, django-models

So, I'm making an item checkout app for our internal group. So, my django app has a model of an item, with one of the fields being `loanedTo`.

We have a database of users in the building, and I would like to set the choices field of this `loanedTo` field to take values from the db. So, when someone checks out an item, he can select from a list of users.

I can't seem to find how to do this exactly?

On here, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/, the choices field can be set to an iterable list or tuple.

Comment: What kind of field is `loanedTo` in you model? If it is a `ForeignKey`, the default widget should be a select with a list of users.

Comment: This seems like a very general, intro-level question. I suspect any django introductory tutorial will cover this.

Comment: Yeah, the loanedTo is a Foreign key, and yeah this is a basic question but I wasn't able to find an example where they show how to connect to a list of users from an existing database.